# Yii2: Render module view from main application

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-module

How can a Yii2 application [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html) (not a module controller) render a view that is provided by a module, assuming the module follows the directory structure outlined in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#creating-modules)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in method [render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#render()-detail) you can specify view as:

- path alias (e.g. "@app/views/site/index"); absolute path within application (e.g. "//site/index"): the view name starts with double slashes. The actual view file will be looked for under the view path of the application.
- absolute path within module (e.g. "/site/index"): the view name starts with a single slash. The actual view file will be looked for under the view path of $module.
- relative path (e.g. "index"): the actual view file will be looked for under $viewPath.

So in the case of the module mentioned by you do this in the action:

```
return $this->render('@app/modules/forum/views/default/index');
```

This will render the view with applied layout of the main application. To use module's layout add this as well in the action:

```
$this->layout = '@app/modules/forum/views/layouts/main';
```

This assumes view `default/index` and layout `main` in the `forum` module.

Comment: I'd like to add one important and incredibly useful fact: yii2 extensions installed via composer automatically get their own `@vendorname/extensionname` alias.